# Refresh a page in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, refresh

How to refresh the current page in MVC.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Request()
{
    if (Session["type"] != null  && Session["resulttype"] != null)
    {
        return View();
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I want to refresh my page in else part. That is when return null value.

Comment: you can use `Redirect` or `RedirectToAction` to reload

Comment: Its not working....because the browser show that its redirect to another page and again redirect to another...ie, a cycle formed..

Comment: What do you want to achieve? This does not seem right

Comment: just want to refresh the current page...\

Comment: if you refresh page again cycle is formed...it will again come in else part... better redirect to another page

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use `Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()`

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Request()
{

    if (Session["type"] != null  && Session["resulttype"] != null)
        return View();
    else
        return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the following code in asp.net core

```
public IActionResult Index(){
         return Redirect($"{Request.Path.ToString()}{Request.QueryString.Value.ToString()}");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Just Redirect to the Action you want to redirect to. It will refresh your page.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Request()
    {
        if (Session["type"] != null  && Session["resulttype"] != null)
        {
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Request");
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Indianprogrammer According to Object Oriented Programming concept=>
If you will return the 'RedirectToAction' then your method execution completes.
else 'RedirectToAction' will be used as a Method for Processing something.

Comment: This won't refresh the page. Suppose you are on the Home Controller's Index Action and you make changes to the page by performing a post function. If you use RedirectToAction("Index"), this won't refresh the page as the control is still on the Index action of the Home controller.

Comment: @Aditya Have you tested that? RedirectToAction always returns a redirect to the browser, regardless whether it's the same page.  This will prompt browser to redirect.  If it's the same page the effect is a refresh.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `location.href = location.href;` in Javascript code after calling a `buttonclick` or after a action method call like.

```
$('#btnme').click(function () {
   location.href = location.href;
}
```